# Trying to get Karma tests up with EmberJS using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript, karma-runner

I'm trying to use http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/RequireJS.html to get my tests up and running. My `karma.conf.js` file is:

// Karma configuration
// Generated on Wed Feb 12 2014 13:35:05 GMT-0500 (EST)

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: 'scripts',
    frameworks: ['qunit', 'requirejs'],
    files: [
      '../tests/test-bootstrap.js',
      {pattern: '../tests/**/*Spec.js', included: false}
    ],
    exclude: [

    ],
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

My `test-bootstrap.js` file is:

```
tests = [];

for (file in window.__karma__.files) {
  if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
    if (/Spec\.js$/.test(file)) {
      tests.push(file);
    }
  }
}

console.log(tests);

requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: "scripts",
  paths: {
    jquery: "../lib/jquery",
    underscore: "../lib/underscore"
  },
  shim: {
    underscore: {
      exports: "_"
    }
  },
  deps: tests,
  callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

How do I get this to allow CoffeeScript files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to precompile your coffeescript files. Have a look at https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coffee-preprocessor

Comment: See the readme in the link above as well as http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/preprocessors.html